# Are ngXS selectors fired on the page init, without any changes of the state slice that returned?

Tags: select, css-selectors, ngxs

I have a selector and I subscribe to them on ngOnInit; but the code inside the subscribe is executed every time when the page is initialized (refreshed).

```js
@Select(SurveysSelectors.deleteSurveys) deleteSurveys$: Observable<IDeleteSurveys>;

.
.
.

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.deleteSurveys$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), debounceTime(600)).subscribe((result: IDeleteSurveys) => {
    if (!result.surveyDeleteResult.esriUpdate) {
      return;
    }

    this.esriUpdate(result.surveyIds, result.surveyDeleteResult.iotFunc);
  });
}
```

Is this normal? I expected that the code inside subscribe to run only when a change is made on the slice of state that selector returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is expected since your `ngOnInit` will run every time your component is initialized. In NGXS the selectors are hot and always will emit on subscription the last value, in this case the initial value. A possible workaround would be to use a `skip(1)` to be sure you only react to changes that happen after you subscribed.

Example below:

```
this.deleteSurveys$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), skip(1), debounceTime(600)).subscribe((result: IDeleteSurveys) => {
  if (!result.surveyDeleteResult.esriUpdate) {
    return;
  }

  this.esriUpdate(result.surveyIds, result.surveyDeleteResult.iotFunc);
});
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: This is a good workaround but my final solution was to clear the state after it was  consumed